# DotNetNuke will not save from editor

Tags: cookies, dotnetnuke, fckeditor

A DNN site version 05.02.00(275)
When editing a HTML module the following happens:
If I make the changes and save before the cookie "portalaliasid" expires (within 1 minute) all is well.

BUT if I stay in the editor for a longer time, say 2 minutes, and posting I end up at the editor again with the old content. All my previous work is lost.

Now I'm lost - is this a bug, a bad setting or what?

/Staffan

Comment: How do you know the cookie - portalalisid is expiring - much of that has nothing to do with cookies 

Do you get logged out as well?

Comment: The expire date for the cookie I get from checking the responses in Fiddler.
No I don't get logged out - My changes are simply not saved. /Staffan

Comment: Some more information if anybody has a clue about this.

If I save within a short time, say 2 minutes, I get redirected (HTTP/1.1 302 Found) to the same page in view mode:
Location: http://<siteurl>/sstest/tabid/172/language/en-US/Default.aspx

If I stay some minutes longer I get redirected to the edit mode of the same page:
Location: http://<siteurl>/sstest/tabid/172/ctl/Edit/mid/584/language/en-US/Default.aspx

I can verify the redirect by looking at the http traffic in Fiddler.
TIA
/Staffan

Comment: Stock or custom dnn build? Did you check the page source for meta refresh or javascript weirdness? Same results using the html module on a new page?

Comment: You may also want to test with the default skin...